# Using pandas, how to use dataframe to find a column value if another column is not null?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a csv file bellow:

df.csv

```
Symbol  Total Volume (on 01/17/2018)
A   
B   
C       1.900
D   
E   
F   
G       1.051
```

I would like to find the **Symbols** if the **Total Volume (on 01/17/2018)** value is not null. In another words, I would like to retung "G", in this case.

I was tryng to do it with those lines of code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./df.csv')
type_filter = df[df['Total'].str.match('', case=False)]
    a = type_filter['Symbol']
print type_filter
```

Any ideas?

By the way, could you also give me an example if I would like to find the Symbols if the Total value is null?

Comment: `df.Symbol[df.Total.str.strip().ne('')]` And for the inverse, invert the condition with `~`.

Comment: I've edited the question, could you check it again, and see if this works?

Comment: For your edit, it should return C and G, right?

Comment: yes, it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.strip` with a not equals comparison with `ne`, and use the resultant mask to index `df` -

```
df

  Symbol Total Volume
0      A             
1      B             
2      C        1.900
3      D             
4      E             
5      F             
6      G        1.051
```

```
df.loc[df['Total Volume'].str.strip().ne(''), 'Symbol']
```

Or, if you have a numeric column with NaNs -

```
df.loc[df['Total Volume'].notnull(), 'Symbol']

2    C
6    G
Name: Symbol, dtype: object
```

Comment: it is returning this: 
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: BTW, when I `print(df)` the empty cells return "NaN"

Comment: What if I would like to look in two columns, what should I do?

Comment: @rafasalo `df.loc[df['Total Volume'].notnull(), ['col1', 'col2']]`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain right. If I have a third column. Like: Symbol, Total Volume and Percentage, and I want to look at `notnull()` in Total Volume and Percentage?

Comment: @rafasalo And it should be not null in all the columns? Or at least one?

Comment: @COLDSPEED not null in all the columns.

Comment: @rafasalo `df.loc[df[['Total Volume', 'Symbol']].notnull().all(1), 'Symbol']` Use `all`.

Comment: @COLDSPEED is returning this error: KeyError: ('Total Volume', 'Percentage')

Comment: @rafasalo Don't pass it as a tuple, pass it as a list. There's a difference. Do `df[list(columns)].notnull().all(1)` if it comes from a variable.

Comment: I'm tring with this one:
`a = df.loc[df['Total'].notnull(), 'Symbol']
b = df.loc[df['percentage'].notnull(), 'Symbol']


print df[['a','b']]`

But I'm getting this: `KeyError: "['a' 'b'] not in index"`

Comment: @rafasalo They are variables, not columns. That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found how:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./df.csv')
type_filter = df[df['Total'].notnull()]
a = type_filter['Symbol']
print type_filter
```